# How to set Object to data in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I want to set object to data in React.

I know how to do in jquery but not in React.

How to do it?

Jquery example.

```
<button id="set" onClick="set()">set</button>
<button id="restore" onClick="restore()">restore</button>
```

```
set = () => {
  $('#set').data('date', dayjs());  
}

restore = () => {
  alert($('#set').data('date').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
}
```

If I click 'set' button, current date object of dayjs set to the object #set.
If I click 'restore' button, get dayjs object from #set and alert it.

data('date') is not string. dayjs object. so, i can format directly.

You can check with:
https://codepen.io/sforest1975/pen/qBMgxeR

I can find how to use data in string, but not in object, in React.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState`. It is a common library used for saving and setting states in React.
In this demonstration i will use functional components, with name DateSet. Dont forget to install the npm package of dayjs ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)) and import it to your project

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
  import dayjs from 'dayjs'

    const DateSet = () => {
        const [date,setDate] = useState()

       return(<div>
       <button onClick={()=>setDate(dayjs())}>set</button>
       <button onClick={()=>window.alert(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'))}>restore</button>
       </div>
    )}
export default DateSet
```

when you click your 'set' button, a dayjs object will be saved on state named `date` using `setDate` function that have been written above. then when you click 'restore' button, you will get alert of the date by passing the `date` state

Comment: thank you for your reponse. i'll try with this method!
if anyone have other way to solve the problem. let me know